# How to check is ipv4 which presented as ipv6

Tags: sql, mariadb, ipv6, ipv4

In my app, IPv4 addressing represented as IPv6 when I stored it to database. I stored both IPv4 and IPv6 string to database. So How can I check IP string which I get from database is IPv4 or IPv6. For example:`IPv4: 192.168.98.62`represented as IPv6 `0x00000000000000000000FFFFC0A8623E`. I want to check it by Mariadb code. Could you please to help me!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like

> 0x00000000000000000000FFFF
>    is before your hex encoded IP-Adress.

The IP following is C0A8623E with two digits for every net.

You could make a stringmatch on the beginning of the Ipv6 String. 
Example:

```
IPString LIKE '0x00000000000000000000FFFF%'
```

This should tell you if it's a v6 or v4 address.

Hope this helps.

Best regards,

Georg

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Georg.Duees. And I found another solution is use mariadb function: `IS_IPV4_MAPPED(UNHEX('2001CDBA000000000000000032579652'))`

Comment: Well your solution looks much cleaner, keep it up 

Comment: This is probably the way to use it:  `IS_IPV4_MAPPED(UNHEX('00000000000000000000FFFFC0A8623E'))`